# Series problem - finding the a and d values from given terms

Tags: sequences-and-series

EDIT -

[here's a screenshot of the question](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-SnHZxC4IWQU/VM-eP2qhVoI/AAAAAAAAcJY/-Swjc4AB4_g/w1194-h243-no/a.png)

[Here's a shot of the answer](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-nh1-6dInTiA/VM-emFjN9mI/AAAAAAAAcJk/BpwjG1r8INM/w654-h83-no/a.png)

---

I'm trying to do a series problem and keep on going wrong. The question is :

---

$$\text{The sum of the first two terms of an arithmetic series is 47}$$
$$\text{The 13th term of this series is -62. Find:}$$
$$\text{a. the first term of the series and the common difference }$$
$$\text{b. the sum of the first 60 terms of the series}$$

---

So what I have tried is as follows :

The question has given the sum of the first two terms, so I should be able to use this as a series in itself, and say that :

$$a = a$$
$$n = 2$$
$$d = d$$
$$sum = 47$$
$$47 = 2a + d $$

Then looking at the other piece of information the 13th term is -62. So I know that it's going to be a negative common difference, and that -62 will be :

$$-62 = a + (n-1)d$$
$$-62 = a + 12d$$

I can then use simultaneous equations to solve for a and d.

$$\text{eq[1]: 47 = 2a + d} $$ 
$$\text{eq[2]: -62 = a + 12d} $$ 
$$\text{multiply equation 2 by 2 then calculate eq[1] - eq[2]}$$
$$\text{equation 3 : }2(eq[2]) = -124 = 2a + 24d$$
$$\text{then work out eq[1] - eq[3] which leaves :}$$
$$171 = 0a - 23d$$
$$\text{So I should be able to say that the value for d is }-\frac{171}{23}$$

But this answer is wrong, it also looks wrong. But that's just because it's not a nice number and the questions in my level usually have nice number answers, which probably isn't great logic going forwards but still.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, no doubt something very basic.

Thank you

Comment: Why do you say it's wrong? The solution to the system is $$\begin{cases}a = \frac{626}{23}\\d=-\frac{171}{23}\end{cases}$$

Comment: because the answer is d = -3, a = 25 EDIT -> I've added in screenshots of the book question / answer to the op

Comment: But then $a + 12d = 25 - 36 = -11 \neq -62$

Comment: I've added screenshots of the books question / answer, perhaps I've misunderstood something. thanks @rubik

Comment: It's the thirtieth term (30th) not the thirteenth (13th).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the question is saying that the $30th$ element of the progression is $-62$.

For the record, I find ordinal numbers' names horribly confusing. In fact, I didn't even know that a thing such as *thirtieth* existed!

Taking this into account, we have the following system
$$\begin{cases}47 = 2a + d\\
-62 = a + 29d
\end{cases}$$
which indeed gives $a = 25$ and $d = -3$.

But remember: beyond the actual problem the most important thing is the method, and yours was working (albeit for a different version of the problem).

Comment: oh no! This happens to me far too regularly, I seem to be constantly merging questions together and trying to solve something far more awkward than the original... And yes, *thirtieth* definitely registered as 13th for me! I guess the author had a penchant for magic eyes as well, thanks for your help